# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function :jquery.maphilight.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

http://midnightshealing.poweredhub.com/roi-scan/

This is the site which i am tryin to develop.
there is some wierd problem.
You can see in the console window.
It Says-

```
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"
```

I know, when this error comes generally.
ie. calling a function before declaring it.

i am calling jquery.maphilight.js first,
and then,
calling AllScripts1.js in which i am initialising the above plugin by.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img[usemap]').maphilight({ stroke: false, fillColor: '009DDF', fillOpacity: 0.5, alwaysOn: true });   //change default color here
});
```

i am not able to find wt i hv done wrong.
any help will be appreciated. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure img[usemap] really exists in the page?

Comment: Yes.
<img src="http://midnightshealing.poweredfiles.com/DRAG-DROP/Humansm.png" usemap="#human" border="0">
this is that html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have included jQuery twice, which is probably the reason for the error.

The first jQuery is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

And the second one is here:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://midnightshealing.poweredhub.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
```

You need to get rid of either one of them in order to fix the issue.

Comment: Jquery is working fine on that page.
The problem is with some thin else know.??

Comment: Why don't you just try doing what i'm suggesting? Usually duplicate jQuery instances cause similar issues. I've had such situation at least a dozen times, and removing the second jQuery instance has always fixed the issue.