# undefined is not a function in maphilight.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemap

I'm having trouble with the seemingly straightforward plugin: https://github.com/kemayo/maphilight

I've tried innumerable things, and keep getting: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` from my one line of code in main.js.

I'm using the latest stable releases of jquery and maphilight.

main.html:

```
<body>
    <img class="img_map" usemap="#regional_map">
    <map name="regional_map">
        <area ...... />
        <area ...... />
    </map>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.maphilight.js" type="text/html"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
</body>
```

main.js:

```
$(".img_map").maphilight();
```

Comment: Helped me as well [and also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511903/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-jquery-maphilight-js)

Answer (score 2):

You are including your maphilight javascript file with `text/html`. Try this:

```
<script src="js/jquery.maphilight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

a) I highly suggest to include your script tags in the:

```
<head></head>
```

b) Try this in your main.js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.img_map').maphilight();
});
```

c) and this in your html:

```
<img class="img_map"></img>
```

Comment: actually good practice to load scripts from end of body tag so other resources load sooner

Comment: I get that but especially when you are just setting something up, it's a good practice to do everything the safe way. 

Once you set up a demo, then you can change it step by step. It helps avoid small errors that happen due to us missing small details.